# Definition of perturbation using norms

Tags: numerical-methods, perturbation-theory

Can someone give me the definition of a perturbation vector? I know that it is a vector composed of $x_i$ that have a small value and are independent, but I know I can define it by using norms because my teacher told me this. My teacher doesn't answer my mails and I need this definition for tomorrow.

Comment: Welcome to math.stackexchange! If you would like other users to help you, it may be helpful to provide some more details and background to your question.

Comment: It's going to depend somewhat on context; for example, "independent" doesn't mean anything in just vector analysis by itself, so it sounds like you're doing something with some randomness involved.

Comment: I am studying statistics, so I have another definition for "error" or "perturbation". I need a definition for "perturbation" using norms because I have to write an essay for my numerical analysis class. My teacher explained that the perturbation vector is a vector composed by \epsilon_i that are values that are "small enough", then he put a condition for the vector using norms but I can't find it.

Comment: You have $0<\| \epsilon \| \ll 1$ but what exactly this means is going to depend on what you're studying as a function of the perturbed point $x+\epsilon$.

Comment: Thanks, that's enough.